# React, Nextjs, TailwindCSS. Scroll not working

Tags: reactjs, scroll, next.js, scrollbar, tailwind-css

I am facing a problem that in React Next.js, I am unable get the scroll bar vertically. This is my code:

```html
        <div className=" hover:bg-violet-400 box-content overflow-y-scroll w-4000">
          <div ref={scrollRef}>
            {message.map((m) => (
              <Message
                message={m}
                own={m.sender === sender[0]._id}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am using Tailwind Css in this project. The 'overflow-y-scroll' doesnt work. The overflow still happens even this property is empty.

Comment: If you mean that the scrollbars still appear when your message array is empty, you might try using the utility class `overflow-y-auto` instead of `overflow-y-scroll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the height of your `div` to make your content scrollable inside it. And I just noticed you used `w-4000` which is not a tailwind class. So change this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `w-4000` and add `w-screen` then If your content takes more space than the width, the vertical scrollbar will be available